# Disable Remote web inspector on production versions of the app

Tags: ios, cordova

I am a bit worried that Safari's remote web inspector might be used for accessing my app's source code during runtime. A quick test with an IPA seems to suggests that this feature is disabled in non debug mode.

I thought I would double check with you. Any advice ? do I need to add any extra measures to ensure it is disabled ?

Jamil

Comment: One can access your source of Phonegap project anyway by converting IPA to ZIP and then extracting it: http://vivianaranha.com/hacking-into-phonegap-iphoneipad-apps/

Comment: I agree but I dont want them to be able to debug it during runtime. (e.g. get access tot he data coming from the native layer)